# View High score page on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to Create a page for my game where you can view the latest high score. Currently, when I try to run this my program crashes and I am unable to figure out why. Any help would be great!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.high_score);

    TextView highscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.high_scores);
    highscore.setText(GamePanel.highScore);

    //set to full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: what is GamePanel and where is it created?

Comment: GamePanel is a class where the main body of my game is created, it's in the same Android file but when I try to view high score my app crashes.

Comment: and where is it created? is highscore static?

Comment: Put GamePanel code and show the logcat